# How to create volume with absolute path from Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, boot2docker, docker-toolbox

Hi I am using Windows and Docker Toolbox have docker-compose.yml
and I have Windows path which I have to add as volume of the container. I use Virtual box to create the Linux host.

```
version: '3'

db:

  boo-container:
    build: boo-container/
    restart: always
    container_name: boo-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - '/c/users/xelian/project/foo:/work/project/foo:rw'
```

the container is created but the /work/project/foo is empty.I tied with double quotes. But nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Docker 18.06:

```
version: '3'

db:

  boo-container:
    build: boo-container/
    restart: always
    container_name: boo-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - 'c:/users/xelian/project/foo:/work/project/foo:rw'
```